# CreateCompatibleBitmap and DPI Scaling?

Tags: winapi, bitmap, scaling, dpi

Could someone explain what I'm missing with regards to DPI Scaling and CompatibleBitmaps?   I start up an High-Aware app at 144DPI.  I then switch to 96DPI.   The resolution reported via `GetMonitorInfo()` has changed from `2560x1600` to `3840x2400`. I now use `GDI` to `CreateCompatibleDC()`, `CreateCompatibleBitmap()` using the resolution reported `3840x2400`, I `BitBlt()` from the screen to the DC.  Later I use the `HBITMAP` created with `CreateCompatibleBitmap()` to `BitBlt()` back to the screen but now the screen area captured shows much smaller than the full screen (in upper left corner) with black filling in the rest of the screen.  If I save the bitmap to a file to look at it, it actually is a bitmap `3840x2400`.   I thought `BitBlt()`, `CompatibleBitmaps`, and GDI in general supported the automatic scaling for the DPI change.  I would have expected it to fill the screen exactly as it was since both getting from the screen and putting to the screen use `BitBlt()`.  What am I missing?

TIA!!

Comment: If you're DPI aware then the system does no auto-scaling for you at all (except for window frames). A bitmap is just a bitmap, its size doesn't change for DPI. When a non-DPI aware app blits a bitmap to the screen the system will scale it but when a DPI-aware app does it then it's blitted as is.

Comment: I thought High-Aware would auto scale when the DPI different than what it was when the app started.   Also, the change by GetMonitorInfo() seems to reflect some type of scaling?

Comment: If you tell the OS you're DPI aware you're telling it you can handle the scaling.

Comment: High-Aware aka System-Aware: When the application is moved to a display with a different scale factor, or if the display scale factor otherwise changes, Windows will bitmap scale the application's windows,

Comment: You need to handle the DPI scale for the bitmap yourself. Record the dpi when the program starts, and then get the dpi again after `GetMonitorInfo`, and then calculate 
 the scale and physical coordinates instead of virtual coordinates.

Comment: If I left the app in High-DPI aware mode, how do I get the actual DPI?  GetDpiForWindow(), GetDpiForMonitor(), and GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSX) all return the system DPI and not the actual current DPI?

Comment: Sorry for the confuse, the issue seems to be the resolution, you could use [`QueryDisplayConfig`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-querydisplayconfig) to get the actual resolution in the display settings.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce this issue, According to the [`PROCESS_SYSTEM_DPI_AWARE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellscalingapi/ne-shellscalingapi-process_dpi_awareness):

> System DPI aware. This app does not scale for DPI changes. It will
> query for the DPI once and use that value for the lifetime of the app.
> If the DPI changes, the app will not adjust to the new DPI value. It
> will be automatically scaled up or down by the system when the DPI
> changes from the system value.

The value obtained by `GetMonitorInfo` is automatically scaled up or down by the system.
But the bitmap create from `CreateCompatibleBitmap` do not need a scaled size.

You could use [`EnumDisplaySettingsEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumdisplaysettingsexa) or [`QueryDisplayConfig`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-querydisplayconfig) to get the current resolution.

Sample for `QueryDisplayConfig`:

```
HDC hDC = GetDC(NULL);
/*DISPLAY_DEVICE device = { 0 };
device.cb = sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE);
DEVMODE devmode = { 0 };
devmode.dmSize = sizeof(DEVMODE);
EnumDisplayDevices(NULL, 0, &device, 0);
EnumDisplaySettingsEx(device.DeviceName, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &devmode, 0);
int nWidth = devmode.dmPelsWidth;
int nHeight = devmode.dmPelsHeight;
POINTL postion = devmode.dmPosition;*/

UINT32 numPathArrayElements = 0, numModeInfoArrayElements = 0;
UINT32 filter = QDC_ONLY_ACTIVE_PATHS;
GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes(filter, &numPathArrayElements, &numModeInfoArrayElements);

DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO* pathArray = new DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO[numPathArrayElements];
DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO* modeInfoArray = new DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO[numModeInfoArrayElements];
ZeroMemory(pathArray, sizeof(DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO) * numPathArrayElements);
ZeroMemory(modeInfoArray, sizeof(DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO) * numModeInfoArrayElements);
QueryDisplayConfig(filter, &numPathArrayElements, pathArray, &numModeInfoArrayElements, modeInfoArray, NULL);
int ix = pathArray[0].sourceInfo.modeInfoIdx; //assuming path[0] is primary
int nWidth = modeInfoArray[ix].sourceMode.width;
int nHeight = modeInfoArray[ix].sourceMode.height;
//POINTL postion = modeInfoArray[ix].sourceMode.position;
HDC memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
HBITMAP memBM = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, nWidth, nHeight);
SelectObject(memDC, memBM);
BitBlt(memDC, 0, 0, nWidth, nHeight, hDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
PBITMAPINFO pbi = CreateBitmapInfoStruct(hWnd, memBM);
CreateBMPFile(hWnd,L"test.bmp",pbi,memBM, memDC);
BitBlt(hDC, 0, 0, nWidth, nHeight, memDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
```

For multiple displays, you may need to determine which one you want to use from the start position and width + height.